# @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I keep getting this error:

> public final class MainViewModel extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
> ^
> @HiltViewModel annotated class should contain exactly one @Inject annotated constructor.
> [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

Here is my MainViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: DefaultRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val items = repository.getItems().asLiveData()
}
```

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Did you use multiple constructors in your ViewModel? Otherwise it should work

Comment: @Anand Yes. Multiple times. Doesn't work.

Comment: @0xAliHn I provided the entire ViewModel code here. There are no other constructors

Comment: What's the import for the `Inject` annotation?

Comment: @HenryTwist `import javax.inject.Inject`

Comment: `Run with --stacktrace` with this try getting more stack trace that might help, the details you shared are not helping, because your `viewmodel` is correct, there might be some other issues.

Comment: This might sound weird but I had a package name called `<domain>.<app_name>.data.default` which was containing the`DefautRepository`. This `default` in the package name was causing the issue. I renamed the package now everything is working fine.

Comment: How interesting. Probably a clash with the Java keyword!

Comment: Are you trying to inject any variables inside your viewmodel? In that case just remove those and add them to the constructor, that should fix your issue

Comment: Same issue as @AtickFaisal, I had `throws` in the package name and changing it fixed the issue

Comment: same issue as @TylerTurnbull and Atick Faisal, i had **new** in the package name, renaming it fixed the issue

Comment: I have faced the same issue by creating <domain>.<case> package. Just rename `case` into `usecase`

Answer (score 18):

When it happened to me, it was because someone removed the injected constructor from class I was injecting.

It was:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel : ViewModel()
```

But needed to be:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was specifying default values for some of my primary constructor parameters. Getting rid of the default values fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using this inject annotation

```
import javax.inject.Inject
```

instead of this one

```
com.google.inject.Inject
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that one of the packages was called "case", which is a name used by some conventions (like of SQL, or even Java).

@Atick Faisal (see comments above) had also another problem with package name, so I guess it might worth a check if you don't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I figured it out after wasting 3 goddam hours on this. Apparently, you cannot name your package by [keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#soft-keywords)

I was using `enum`, and a few people in the comments were using `case`, `default` etc.

If only the error message was a bit clearer (－‸ლ).

NB: This is my assumption and it makes sense too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your module you have `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` instead of `@InstallIn(ApplicationComponentManager::class)`